# Magento script problem with encoding

Tags: php, script

I have problem with magento and encoding :( i've created php script which imports products into magento (by php api). Almost everything is fine.... BUT after import i don't have polish characters in product details ;( only some strange characters.... While import script is running i make var_dump on product name and evetything is fine (i have proper polish signs in script output). My local.xml contains:

```
<initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
```

Database setup is proper too, all database/tables has proper encoding (utf8). After manual product creation on Magento backend i have proper polish chars in product details.

I've checked script encoding and everything is ok (US-ASCII -- is -- a subset of UTF-8)

```
importProducts.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

Any other ideas?

---

EDIT:

Ok, I,ve solved the problem! The solution was append

```
<charset>utf8</charset>
```

to database configuration in local.xml,

Comment: have you tried using utf-8 / utf8_general_ci as encoding on the importscript? If yes, result?

Comment: Yes iI was trying to convert script file by this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv nothing happend :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve problem! The solution was simple, just append

```
<charset>utf8</charset>
```

to database configuration in local.xml.

Answer (score 2):

My script had issues with the utf8mb4 charset... It worked fine inside mysql with the utf8mb4_unicode_ci coalition on the table, database and column. The problem turned out to be that app/etc/local.xml is cached somewhere in magento. Clicking flush cache fixed the problem.

to reiterate

```
<initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8mb4]]></initStatements>
```

should work.